# Can't match-where-limit in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

It's a simple query, but for some reason it's not working

```
SELECT (n:myBaseLabel) WHERE NOT n:myPossibleSubLabel LIMIT 20
```

This is the most simple case, where I really don't care what gets returned. The objective is to run

```
SELECT (n:myBaseLabel) WHERE NOT n:myPossibleSubLabel AND NOT n:myExclusionLabel SET n:myExclusionLabel LIMIT 25000
```

in a loop to iteratively apply the label `myExclusionLabel` to instances of `myBaseLabel` that don't have `myPossibleSubLabel`. Both the iterative loop and the existence of this exclusion label are for performance reasons in querying the graph, since it has ~50M nodes. Since I'm looping and excluding, I don't care about which get tagged in a given loop, I just want to reduce the memory load while breaking the execution into chunks so I don't entirely lock up the database for a day updating this.

However, in the simple test case I keep getting an error at the `I` of `LIMIT`, saying:

> Invalid input 'I': expected 'o/O' (line 1, column 58 (offset: 57))

which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out how. Very unintuitively, you need to limit before the operation after a  `WITH`.

```
MATCH (n:myBaseLabel)
WHERE NOT n:myPossibleSubLabel AND NOT n:myExclusionLabel 
WITH n
LIMIT {updateChunk}
SET n:myExclusionLabel 
RETURN count(n)
```